# How to cut one pandas column in python, and make the other column equal in length?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe consisting of a few columns, among these are X, Y and Z coordinates. Now there columns are all of equal length. If you imagine a cylinder, what I am looking to do is to cut a part of the cylinder so that it gets shorter. I have managed to figure out how to cut column Z with respect to the actual values in column Z:
`cutted_z = [i for i in df["Z"] if i >= 0 and i <= 1000]`

How can one cut X Y Z equally with respect to the actual numerical values in Z?

The problem with my current solution is that it leaves the the length of the X and Y columns, as well as the rest of the columns in my dataframe, untouched, meaning X and Y now have more columns in Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do:

```
mask = (df['Z'] >= 0) & (df['Z'] <= 1000) #creates a mask to filter dataframe on

df = df[mask]
```

This will give you a slice of dataframe for Z values range you wanted.